# how true put try: and exception: inside beautifulsoup and file open to skip IOError

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import json
import re
import os
import sys
import csv


with open("C:/Users/Administrator/Pictures/$sample") as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter='\n'): 
        for bokep in row:
            url = "file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/artikel/$/{}.html".format(" ".join(bokep.split()))
            jazz = open(r"C:/Users/Administrator/Videos/$/{}.html".format(" ".join(bokep.split())), 'r').read()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(jazz, "html.parser")
            with open("C:/Users/Administrator/Videos/$sample/%s.txt" % bokep, "w") as f:

                for wrapper in soup.find_all('div', {
                "class": "sample"
                }, limit = 1):
                    out = wrapper.text.encode('utf-8').strip().replace('\n', '')
                    link = json.loads(out)["sample"]
                    title = json.loads(out)["s"]
                    f.write((bokep) + "sample")

                f.write("sample")

                for wrapper in soup.find_all('div', {
                "class": "sample"
                }, limit = 30):
                    out = wrapper.text.encode('utf-8').strip().replace('\n', '')
                    link = json.loads(out)["sample"]
                    title = json.loads(out)["s"]
                    f.write("sample")
                f.write("sample")
                f.close()
```

this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sample.py", line 11, in <module>
    with open("C:/Users/Administrator/Pictures/$sample") as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/Administrator/Pictures/$
cabinet'
```

My question, how to be able to skip the error, for example in the file

```
C: /Users/Administrator/Pictures/$sample.txt
```

in the first row there

```
example90
example91
example92
etc
```

but in the directory C:/Users/Administrator/Videos/$/ no name example90, then the script will skip to the first line will then continue to the second row without script stops and until the line in the file C:/Users/Administrator/Pictures/$sample.txt exhausted.I've tried to edit but always error and therefore you will help me an appreciation of all. thank you

Comment: You may try using os.isfile(path) before opening a file.
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html is worth reading too.

Comment: no, that not my purpose. above code script for get file is no problem, that my question how yo skip the error if the file no exist in folder..